# Some question about output shape of joint coordinate in cnn-regression

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, cnn

I have some question about output shape of cnn-regression problem.

Let say I have Image shape with

```
image shape = (105, 157, 3)
```

and this image has `14` joint coordinates for each image `(14, 3, 10000)`.

I guess `10000` is the number of pictures

and each joint coordinates looks like

```
y=array([[145.82985678,  95.5022898 ,   1.        ],
         [111.87785389,  83.38437237,   1.        ],
         [  0.        , -27.29260682,   0.        ],
         [146.22287032,  67.62016267,   1.        ],
         [114.716285  ,  89.0394005 ,   1.        ],
         [147.03073148,  90.65512282,   1.        ],
         [  0.        , -27.29260682,   0.        ],
         [  0.        , -27.29260682,   0.        ],
         [  0.        , -27.29260682,   0.        ],
         [102.99138111,  63.60269094,   1.        ],
         [107.44553454,  91.85599752,   1.        ],
         [112.68571505, 118.12240233,   1.        ],
         [ 95.72063065,  64.38871802,   1.        ],
         [ 76.74681039,  60.37124629,   1.        ]])
```

If I want to make a neural network then the neural network should have output and output should compare with this y true value

1. What is the output should shape with?
2. Which shape do I have to reshape this y true value? and how?

---

Dataset is from `Leeds Sports Dataset` (LSP): 11000 training and 1000 testing images from sports activities with challenging in terms of appearance and especially articulations. The majority of people have 150 pixel height. For each person the full body is labeled with total 14 joints.

Comment: I guess the third coordinate is somehow a label rather than a coordinate location.